# Linebreak without text following it

Tags: spacing, graphics

I am working on a presentation in Beamer. On one of the slides I show an image and on the next slide I show an image of the same size but where there is text under the image.

From an aesthetical point of view, I don't want the figure to "move upwards" on the second slide when the text is added.

Is there a way to specify in LaTeX that I want an "empty row" of text under the figure? That is, instead of adding some unneeded text under the first figure, just specify that "here should be an empty line. Treat it as if there was text here"?

Or am I missing some other, smarter, way of solving the problem?

Edit: Here's a minimum working example. Note that image B is placed higher up than image A is.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe} % Needed for the placeholder image

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some slide title}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-a}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some other slide title}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-b}
\end{center}
Here's some interesting text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It will be easy to show how to do this if you will provide the MWE (Minimal working Example) which reproduce your problem. It might help `[t]` position specifier for frame, but as I said, we need more information about your presentation.

Comment: Hello! Yes, that's a good idea. I should have done that straight away. My bad! Thanks for pointing it out. It has now been added.

Comment: Does use of `[t]` frame placement option solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single frame:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\only<1>{Some title}\only<2>{Some other title}}

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics<1>[width=100pt]{example-image-a}%
    \includegraphics<2>[width=100pt]{example-image-b}%
\end{center}

\onslide<2>{Here's some interesting text.}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution. However, I would still need to make a "handout" version, and for that I need the slides to both be present. Wouldn't this solution lead to only the slide with B be shown?